# Is it true that the process of Gaussian Elimination will stop when we obtain a row of 0's?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My feeling is false because we use Gaussian elimination to reduce the system to pivots that give us convenience to find the variables?

I have another question, 'Do we need to apply ALL the three types of elementary row operations in GE?'

Comment: Look at the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\1&1&1\\2&2&2\end{pmatrix}$. Should it end after noting that the first row is all zeros?

Comment: You are correct, Gaussian elimination does not necessarily stop when a row of zeros occurs.  You do not necessarily have to use all three types of elementary row operations to row reduce a matrix--they are available to used, but not required to use all.

Comment: To  @MoonLightSyzygy , my answer is a no. We can reduced row 3 to a row with all 0's

Comment: @user4622 More than we can, we must, since the matrix is not yet in echelon form.

Comment: you can only use 2 (one does not necessarily need to devide, but then you would end in the bottom with the determinant).
Which is a fun exercise to write down